# Как вытащить сегменты фильма из хром

Tags: python, google-chrome

Нужно написать парсер фильма на *Python*. Фильм, как известно, загружается сегментами формата `ts`.
Проблема собственно в том, как получить эти кусочки от хрома.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

С помощью `ChromeCacheView` находил эти файлы в кэше хрома, но там они в сжатом виде. Каких-то библиотек для работы с файлами кэша хрома я не нашел.